# How to manual focus Nikon Coolscan 4000 using Vuescan?

Tags: nikon, manual-focus, scanning, film-scanner

How to be sure that the scanner (Nikon Coolscan 4000) focuses correctly and if not, how can I manually focus it using Vuescan?

Answer (score 6):

The Input Tab has a [focus](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/html/vuesc29.htm#inputfocus) and [auto focus](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/html/vuesc29.htm#inputautofocus) option in Vuescan.

+ lots of experimenting. Don't forget to save your settings regularly in a way you can remember what they are.